# Duplicate a div onclick but put div in at a certain position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to duplicate a div when i press on a certain button, i have this all working fine, except where the div is being added to. It goes to the bottom on my page just above my footer and I would like it to go

```
 document.getElementById('and-button').onclick = duplicate;

   var i = 0;
   var original = document.getElementById('filter');

   function duplicate() {
          var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
          clone.id = "filter" + ++i;
          original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
   }
```

HTML:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
         <div>
           other content etc
         </div>

         <a href=#! id="filter">
           some content
         </a>

        /*here is where i would like my duplicated div to go*/

         <div class="filter-nav">
           <input type="button" onclick="" value="AND" id="and-button">
           <input type="button" onclick="" value="OR" id="or-button">
         </div>

         <div>
           other content etc
         </div>

        /*here is where it is going*/

        <footer>
           footer content
        </footer>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: FYI your `<head>` tag is closed improperly. And why the jQuery tag? I don't see any.

Comment: Noted and fixed was just a retyping error thanks. Because I am not sure how to add in the position I desire  and thought i might need to use jQuery to get there I am very new to it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

added an id to the next node and used insert before to save multiplication

```js
document.getElementById('and-button').onclick = duplicate;

   var i = 0;
   var original = document.getElementById('filter');
   var beforeElem = document.getElementById('filter-nav');
   function duplicate() {
          var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
          clone.id = "filter" + ++i;
          original.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, beforeElem);
   }
```

```html
<div>
           other content etc
         </div>

         <a href=#! id="filter">
           some content
         </a>

        /*here is where i would like my duplicated div to go*/

         <div class="filter-nav" id="filter-nav">
           <input type="button" onclick="" value="AND" id="and-button">
           <input type="button" onclick="" value="OR" id="or-button">
         </div>

         <div>
           other content etc
         </div>

        /*here is where it is going*/

        <footer>
           footer content
        </footer>
```

Comment: Ooo except now instead of duplicating the one original, it is duplicating the two new ones , then 4 then 8 then 16 etc.... Any idea how to fix this?